# QRegExp non-capturing parentheses

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm trying to extract "246" from this text:

```
Responsible: John Doe
Number: 246
Date: 24-12-2005
```

Using QRegExp, the pattern:

```
(?:Number: )\d+
```

I expected to get:

```
246
```

But instead I've got:

```
Number: 246
```

I'm trying to avoid capturing groups.

Comment: Please show the snippet of code you used to print. The output is the whole match, you're probably not using the right function.

Comment: I'm using QRegExp::cap().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a regexp like `Number: (\d+)` -- this will explicitly capture the digits in group 1, which you can get back with `cap(1)`.  `cap(0)` will return the whole match including any non-capturing groups like `(?:Number: )`.

Comment: I know that, I'm trying to avoid capturing groups.

Comment: @TheVTM: no capturing group => you get the complete match, which _includes_ non-capturing groups. If you want to capture a part, you need a capturing group.

Comment: Is this right?
I mean... should be this way?
Cause the reference kind sound the other way.

Comment: Yes, that's right and it's the same in most other regex libraries. Non-capturing groups are groups that don't create new matched groups - the 0th match group conventionally hold the entire matched input.

Comment: And why are you trying to avoid capturing groups? They're exactly what you're looking for - a way to capture a specific substring of the matched input.

Comment: "Using non-capturing parentheses is more efficient than using capturing parentheses since the regexp engine has to do less book-keeping." - [Qt Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qregexp.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(?=Number: (\d+))
```

In this case the whole pattern is not matched cause it is embedded in a zero-length lookahead, the only result is the capturing group

Comment: QRegExp doesnt support \K. :(